# SQL Query Join Same Column Twice

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables -

**Content:**

```
Id | Name | Source | Target         
---------------------------
1  |  Test  |  en   |    de
2  |  Test1 |  en   |    fr
```

and **Locale**:

```
Locale Code | Locale Name
--------------------------
de          |     German
en          |     English
fr          |     French
```

I need all the records from Content table in the form of -

```
1 Test  English German

2 Test1 English French
```

Appreciate your help with the SQL query for this.

Comment: Have you tried _anything_ yourself? This isn't a "do this for me" site, but somewhere to get help with something you've attempted first (usually).

Comment: Just join the same table twice with aliases.

Comment: Got it..I couldn't come up with the idea of joining the same table twice with different aliases. Thanks ta.speot.is.

Comment: Mosty went to the effort of providing an example, you should accept his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
select c.id, c.name, ls.localename Source, lt.localename Target
from content c
join locale ls on c.source = ls.localecode
join locale lt on c.target = lt.localecode
```

Result:

```
+----+-------+---------+--------+
| ID | NAME  | SOURCE  | TARGET |
+----+-------+---------+--------+
|  1 | Test  | English | German |
|  2 | Test1 | English | French |
+----+-------+---------+--------+
```